# Search form does not work in my website

Tags: php, theme-development, search

I have a search form in my website which is located in my header.php and I want it to be shown in all of my pages for this reason I have a searchform.php file where I have inserted this code:

```
<div class="search">
<form method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
<input type="text" name="" placeholder="Search here..."onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onBlur="this.placeholder='Search here...'"/>
</form>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/search-icon.png" alt="search-icon"> 
</div>
```

And in my header.php I have added this piece of code:

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

On the other hand I've put this code inside my search.php file:

```
<p>You searched for " <?php echo esc_html( get_search_query( false ) ); ?> ". Here are the results:</p>
```

Now when I search for something I get no results. What is the problem? please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You're **missing the name** of the *search text input,* so replace:

```
name=""
```

with

```
name="s"
```

Then take a look at `searchform.php` in the default themes, like *Twenty Sixteen*:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <label>
                <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search for:', 'label', 'twentysixteen' ); ?></span>
                <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder', 'twentysixteen' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" />
        </label>
        <button type="submit" class="search-submit"><span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'twentysixteen' ); ?></span></button>
</form>
```

as an example for e.g. attribute escaping.

Comment: I did what you said but it is not fixed. When I search for something I get a with screen with a <p> tag in it sayin: You searched for " What_I_searched_For ". Here are the results:

Comment: shall I add something to functions.php? or install a plugin?

Comment: if your search.php file only contains a single line, then you need to add the loop, see e.g. the default themes.